# MySQLi Query not Returning Results properly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to switch my website over to MySQLi and I'm following the W3schools MySQLi guide to do so. I've hit a roadblock, though. I have a function to check if a specified user is an admin on the site. I've put `echo` in various spots to find where the issue is, and I've figured out that it most likely doesn't see the user. `$username` is set to the variable `$user`. Here's the whole code block (part of connect.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "lark";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
    $user = "";
} else {
    $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}

//functions
function isAdmin($username) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "lark";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql_get_is_admin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $get_is_admin = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_get_is_admin);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($get_is_admin) > 0) {
        echo "num_rows";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_is_admin)) {
            $is_admin_bool = $row['admin'];
            echo "while";
            if($is_admin_bool == 0){
                return false;
            } elseif ($is_admin_bool == 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }


    } else {
        echo "not found.";
    }
}
?>
```

Here's the code I used to test the `$user` variable:

```
<?php 
include("connect.php");
?>
<div class="main">
<h1>Welcome back, <?php echo $user; ?></h1>
foo
<?php
/*if(isAdmin($user) == true) {
    echo   "<div style='display: table-cell;' class='rightcell'>
                <h3 style='color: #000;'>Admin Tools</h3>
                <a href='userlist.php' target='_blank'>Userlist</a>
            </div>";
} else {
} */

echo isAdmin($user);
?>
</div>
```

I also had to reconnect to the database or else I'd get this error on the site:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\lark\connect.php on line 33

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lark\connect.php on line 33

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lark\connect.php on line 35 not found.
```

If I fix it so there's no error, it just says "not found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have $conn in your function, it is commented out.

```
function isAdmin($username) {
    /*$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "lark";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);*/
```

Comment: It was edited out so I could what the error was, my bad. I fixed it.

Comment: And you still get the same errors, this is resolved, or there are other errors? Other error could be you double assign $username.

Comment: I don't get errors, but it says "not found." which means it couldn't find the specified user. The user specified in this case should exist, because it's whoever is logged in. There is a user logged in who is an admin according to the database.

Comment: Yes, you set `$username` twice it is 'root' in your function. You overwrite what you pass in with your sql connection.

Comment: Lol I didn't even notice that. Thanks, this fixed it. I just wish I didn't have to connect to the database within the function even though I already did it once.

Answer (score 2):

the $conn variable is not defined in your function, example:

```
function isAdmin($username) {
global $conn;
..................

}
```